# updating a flag in mysql via radiobutton onclick handler in php

Tags: php, mysql, onclick, radio-button, flags

I want to update a column in a table in mysql. Basically the column is the flag for the entries of that db table.

The modification of the column is resetting all values to 0 and setting the desired row to 1, for this reason I have *post.php* file which looks like

```
<?php
require_once('class.uuid.php');

$connection = mysql_connect("---logindetailshere---");
$db = mysql_select_db("---dbnamehere---",$connection);

switch($_REQUEST['action']){
    case ...
        break;
    case ...
            break;
    case 'changeDisp':
        changeDisp($_REQUEST['uid']);
        break;
}

mysql_close($connection);

...

function changeDisp($uid){
    global $connection, $db;
    $q_string = "UPDATE Questions SET Displayed = 0";
    $query = mysql_query($q_string,$connection) or die( sendError(mysql_error() . '<br/><br/>' . $q_string) );
    $q_string = "UPDATE Questions SET Displayed = 1 WHERE Uid='${uid}'";
    $query = mysql_query($q_string,$connection) or die( sendError(mysql_error() . '<br/><br/>' . $q_string) );
}

?>
```

on the webpage I display the items and radiobuttons next to the items, the purpose is to select the radiobuttons and post to set the flag 1 for the selected item, for this reason I have a *item.php* file

```
    <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($qitem as &$q) {
            $options = explode(";", $q["Options"]);
            $displayed = '';
            if ($q["Displayed"] == 1) { $displayed='checked="yes"'; }

            echo("<div class='item' name='".$q["iUid"]."'>");
            echo("<div class='count'>".$i.".</div>");
            echo ("<div class='radio'><input type='radio' onclick='changeDisp(&#34;".$q["Uid"]."&#34;)' name='disp' ".$displayed."></div>");
            echo("<div class='left'>");
            echo("<h4>".$q["Value"]."</h4>");
            echo("<div class='details'>Typ: ".$q["Type"]."</div>");
            echo("<div class='details'>Skala: ".$options[0]." / ".$options[1]."</div>");
            echo("</div>");
            echo("</div>");
            $i++;
        }   
    ?>
```

here I am using radiobuttons to select the related item, I checked the unique id values using firebug the values are fine, I just want to click on any radiobutton and want to trigger the `onclick=changeDisp()` function.

I have no idea why the page doesn't reload itself and change the selected flag to 1. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wait a minute you are trying to call php function from onClick event ?

Comment: yes, that's what I want to do actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an onclick function to call php function without going there with a javascript, jQuery or ajax call. You could create an ajax script to call the  **post.php** From the **item.php** page and return the results to you.

Here is an example of creating the function you want. This assumes that `$uid` is coming from a radio button and not an actual user input. If the user can directly input something you need to use a **prepared statment**

```
 function changeDisp($uid)
{
$Mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if ($Mysqli->connect_errno)
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $Mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $Mysqli->connect_error;
        $Mysqli->close();
    }           
    $query = "UPDATE Questions SET Displayed = 1 WHERE Uid='".$uid."'";     
    $update = $Mysqli->query($query);
    if($update)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: is there any example that you can share with me? I actually don't know how to do that :/

Comment: It would be hard for me to give you an example. Please do not be offended, but the code you displayed above needs alot of work just to be usable. The logic does not make sense and calling the function you created will not help. As it may update the database, but it does not return a state for you to use. And you would not need to use a `foreach loop`, you could simply use `while`

Comment: Dear Roy, thanks for the answer, I appreciate it. I also think that the code doesn't really make sense, no worries. Currently the line which doesn't do anything is the onclick on the radiobutton. When I check the value it gets, the `$uid` is correctly displayed in Firebug but the parameter is not passing and I am not sure how to make it work using the Ajax call?

Comment: fixed using an Ajax call.